# Ghost - how to get a specific page?

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm a Ghost beginner, and I know I can get the list of pages doing like below.

```
{{#get "pages"}}
{{#foreach pages}}
    {{{html}}}
{{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

But am I able to fetch a specific page? Let's assume that I have an "about" page that I'd like to fetch in order to show its contents into the blog's sidebar, for example, this is what I tried, but it's not working.

```
{{#get "pages/slug/about" as page}}
    {{page}}        // prints undefined
{{/get}}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter passed to the `#get` helper specifies the name of the resource you want to query. It should be either `posts`, `tags` or `authors`. In your use case it should be `posts`.

```
{{#get "posts" slug="pages/slug/about" as |post|}} 
{{#post}}
   <h1><a href="{{slug}}">{{title}}</a></h1> 
   <div class="post-content"> {{content}} </div>
{{/post}} 
{{/get}}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. And what if I want to print the post variable to see its properties? I tried `{{ log post }}` and it returns only [Object object].